# pg_dump: server version: 9.4.21; pg_dump version: 9.3.24 - server version mismatch

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, pg-dump

I'm trying to dump a postgres db from a remote client:

```
pg_dump -Z7 -Fc -h xx.xx.xx.xx -U user dbname > /path/dump/dump.bck
```

This is the error I received:

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.4.21; pg_dump version: 9.3.24
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

The error itself is pretty clear, but unfortunately the remote client where I execute the command is a really old physical file server (ubuntu 14.04) that is impossibile to upgrade.
I have tried to add the postgresql repository in order to install a newer version of pg_dump but the actual os version is not supported anymore.

Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to overcome the problem except by using a more recent client version. Some options:

- install PostgreSQL from source (easier than you think, unless it is Windows)
- use a different client machine, e.g. the database server itself